# What could cause a dramatic increase c#/website webforms project build time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, build, webforms, compilation

My release engineer just informed me that build time for an ASP.net website project doubled (5 minutes to 10), when compared to last release.  Other projects in the solution build in about the same amount of time. The project is mature, so the amount of code increase is not 2x.

What could cause such a slowdown?  Anything I should look out for when comparing this release to last?

Comment: Is there a publishing step?  I have encountered issues where website publishing can take a VERY long time for reasons that are not obvious, and that can happen during the lifecycle of a project for non-obvious reasons.

Comment: Did you check the output window while doing a build to see if there was anything that stood out?

Comment: Brandon I've got him looking into it now.  Eric, not sure how he publishes, I'll ask

Comment: Is this a web site (File->New Web Site), or a web application project (File->New Project)? Does it have a .csproj file?

Comment: @JohnSaunders it's a web application project, no csproj.

Comment: I would suggest reviewing everything that has changed since the last release via source control history. That may lead you to the increase in time if something drastic has changed such as new third party controls added or a new assembly of sorts, etc.

Comment: @offthat I will be doing that with him tomorrow when I'm in the office.  I wanted to see if there was a checklist or something he could follow so that he could do it on his own today.  Thanks.

Comment: @GiovanniGalbo: if it has no .csproj, then it is not a web application project, it's a Web Site "project".

Comment: Possibly a dumb suggestion: Double check that the configuration setup of the solution's projects hasn't changed unexpectedly. Build -> Configuration Manager.

Comment: Is the build trying to pull debug symbols from an external symbol server?

Comment: Is this release build doing something special? i.e. how long does it take to to just run a regular build in VS. Or is it like the previous comments something related to publishing/running test scripts/database scripts?